# Use Observable and HttpClient in Ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, angular-httpclient

What I want is to make GET `http` request in my provider, wrap `http` call in `Observable.create` and return `Observable` object, then in my component, resolve that `Observable`. I tried something, can someone tell me if it is ok (I can't test at the moment so don't know if it works)? If it's not ok, can someone guide me what is the best practice in Ionic 3, to do http call and handle response (success, failure)?

In provider:

```js
public getUsers(credentials):Observable<any> {
   if("some custom condition not satisfied")
       return Observable.throw("ERROR);

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.http.get(API_URL + '/users').subscribe(
        (response) => {
          observer.next(response);
          observer.complete();
        },
        (error)=> {
          return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

then in component:

```js
this.myProvider.login().subscribe(response => {
        if (response.status == 403) {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          console.log("Access denied");
        }

        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.nav.setRoot('MainPage');
      },
      error => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see any need to wrap your http call in another observable. You can simply `return this.http.get(API_URL + '/users');`

Comment: You mean, it already returns `Observable`....so I should avoid creating new one and, return `http` call and subscribe on component...it seems better :)

Comment: But what if I want to do check on the beginning of `getUsers` method, and if something is not ok, throw error? Is it enough to just return `Observable.throw`?

Comment: Yep, it returns an Observable see the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response). There are also [a lot of docs on error handling](https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling) ;)

Comment: Using `Observable.throw` in case of an error seems fine to me.